# Prove using induction,if A $\in$ n and n$\in \omega$ Then A$\in \omega$

Tags: set-theory, advice

**Prove by induction**
If A $\in$ n and n $\in$ ω then A$\in$
ω

Problem is from Pinter’s a book of set theory

**6.1 Definition** By the set of the natural numbers we mean the intersection of all the successor sets. The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol **ω**; every element of ω is called a natural number.

**6.3 Theorem (Mathematical Induction).** Let X be a subset of ω; suppose X has the following properties:

i) $0\in X$.

ii) If $ n\in X$,then $ n^{+} \in X$

Therefore  X = ω.

The Peano axioms for the natural numbers are:

**P1** 0∈ω.

**P2** Ifn∈ω,then n+ ∈ω.

**P3** For each n∈ω,n+ ≠0.r

**P4**. If X is a subset of ω such that

i) 0∈X,and

ii)if n∈X,then n+ ∈X,thenX=ω.

**P5**Ifn,m∈ωandn+ =m+,then n=m.

Attempted proof

P(0):

$0\in A$and  $ 0\subseteq$ ω so $0\in$ω

P(n):
LetA$\in n$,A$\subseteq n$ ,by P2 $n^{+}∈ω.$
and
since $n\in \omega$ ;$n\subseteq\omega$ then n is transitive,
So A$\in. ω $ .

We conclude ω is a transitive set

I tried induction on n?
Help

Comment: Why did I get down voted

Comment: Not sure exactly, but a few things may have caused it. Your title is hard to read (why do you have the colon and stars there) and in the text itself, some things are hard to read (you are missing spaces in some places). Alternatively, it might because your question is not clear. Are you trying to prove Theorem 6.3 or are you trying to prove that "if $A \in n$ and $n \in \omega$ then $A \in \omega$"?

Comment: To indicate I have to use induction. It was suppose to indicate bolder letters

Comment: Prove using  induction If A ∈ n and n ∈ ω then A∈ω The rest are the needed def’s and theorem for it

Comment: Gotcha, my bad. I edited my answer for that Note that it is often helpful to put the question you are asking in the body of the post, not just the title. I know it seems repetitive, but it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note that I originally thought you were trying to prove mathematical induction. This the proof here. I put the proof of your actual question below but leaving this here for completeness).

You are trying to prove Mathematical Induction using induction. You can't do that. One way you can do it is via proof by contradiction.

Assume $X \neq \omega$. So then, since $X\subseteq\omega$, there must be some element(s) in $\omega-X$.

Let $n'=min(\omega-X)$ (which must exist since the natural numbers are well-ordered). By definition, $n'\neq0$ so $n'>0$. Since $n'$ is the smallest natural number not in $X$ this means that $n'-1$ (defined as the number whose successor in $n'$) is in $X$.

But, by definition, since $n'-1 \in X$ then $n' \in X$ which contradicts our assumption. So, $X=\omega$.

(It seems I misunderstood what you were asking. I'll put the proof of your question below here).

Note that $A\in\omega$ means $A$ is a natural number (by definition). So, let's do this by induction.

For $n=0$ this is vacuously true since $0=\emptyset$ so there is no $A\in0$.

Assume its true for $n$, let's prove it for $n+1$. But $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$ so we know, by the induction hypothesis, that it contains only natural numbers and the number $n$. But $n=(n-1)^+$ i.e. its the successor to a natural number, so $n$ is also a natural number so $n\in\omega$.

Comment: I am trying to prove If A ∈n and n ∈ω then A∈ω using induction

Comment: Is your statement “If  n= $(n-1)^{+}$...” related to the theorem every transitive set is a natural number or this 6.4 Lemma Let m and n be natural numbers; if m ∈ n+, then m ∈ n or m = n. So in a nutshell a natural number is a transitive set

Comment: Not all transitive sets are natural numbers. All natural numbers, are, however, transitive sets. Ordinals are transitive sets totally ordered by $\in$ and natural numbers are finite ordinals. That being said, yes, the statement $n=(n-1)^+$ arises from the definition of "successor" and that lemma (and some other theorems/lemmas around ordinals as background).